# Why am I getting classes undefined error?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React, can someone explain to me why I am getting classes undefined error?

Below is the code

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
    root: {
      width: "100%",
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
      overflowX: "auto"
    },
    table: {
      minWidth: 700
    },
    tableRow: {
      "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "purple",
        "& > .MuiTableCell-root": {
          color: "yellow"
        }
      }
    }
  });
export default function MyTable(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <Box>
                <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                    <Table className={classes.table}>
```

I'm getting uncaught runtime errors from classes.table because it's undefined. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How are you using `MyTable`? Are you adding a `classes` attribute to the JSX tag?

Comment: function App(){

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <MyTable/>
        </div>
    );
} I just call it in the app

Comment: That would be why: React matches attributes of the JSX tag to the props the component definition gets, and you aren't passing any, so `classes` is undefined.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks! what should I passing in? is there something default I can use?

Comment: Also, I'm looking at this sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/table-hover-colors-forked-x6mtu9?file=/demo.js:439-445. I don't see any attributes pass in for Demo.

Comment: That example uses the `withStyles` higher-order component that passes the props. Frankly though the answer from ReubenSnm is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you're not passing a `classes` property to the `MyTable` component. This is why you can't destructure `classes` from `props` and get `undefined`.

You can use the `makeStyles` and `createStyles` functions from `@material-ui/core/styles`.

```js
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: "100%",
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
      overflowX: "auto",
    },
    table: {
      minWidth: 700,
    },
    tableRow: {
      "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "purple",
        "& > .MuiTableCell-root": {
          color: "yellow",
        },
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Now you can use the `useStyles` hook in your component to get the classes.

```js
export default function MyTable(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Box>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table className={classes.table}>
            ...
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [MUI v4 styles basics](https://v4.mui.com/styles/basics/) for more information.